# How can I use OpenXml (Office) in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, excel, openxml, silverlight-5.0

I installed this SDK to use OpenXml in my Silverlight application. The purpose is to import data from Excel without have the application installed.

But I realized that I cannot use some assemblies in Silverlight like `System.IO.Packages`, so I have no idea how can I get the data from the Excel.

Does you know free assembly from CodePlex or another site to get some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear for Silverlight is an Excel compatible spreadsheet control for Silverlight which can read and write Open XML files as well as the older xls files.

You can see live SpreadsheetGear for Silverlight samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/silverlight.aspx) or download the free evaluation to try it yourself [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

Is your silverlight application hosted in IIS?
I suppose simpler way is to OpenXml in the server in the asp.net hosting app via Ria services or Wcf services-